# Can a user of a GitHub R package avoid first installing and loading devtools

Tags: r, github, package, rstudio, devtools

Suppose I have an R package on GitHub. Is there any way, I can have an RStudio user of my package avoid first running:

```
install.packages("devtools") 
library(devtools)
```

and just directly use:

```
install_github("My-Github-username/My-package-name")
library(My-package-name)
```

Can I for example make any changes to my R package such that my package automatically does `install.packages("devtools")` and `library(devtools)` for the user?

Comment: Submit it to CRAN? That way you can avoid using devtools completely?

Comment: No. It is not possible to use a function from a package without first installing that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somehow need to get your user to install and build the package locally to use it. The package can't install itself. Think of the package as a collection of code. You somehow need to get the code from GitHub to your user's computer.

If using devtools is not an option, you could have them do this manually (by, say, downloading the `.tar.gz` from GitHub) and then build the package themselves, using `R CMD build` and `R CMD install` such. There are some [nice explanations out there](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/build.html) on how to go about doing this. Using `devtools::install_github()` is a convenient, easy function that takes care of all of those steps for you.

(The exception to my statement "The package can't install itself" is that you can use devtools to install devtools.)